# How fix, Unable to locate Android SDK

Tags: flutter

how to fix this problem? Android toolchain - develop for Android devices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFTm6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Android SDK if you didn't allready. If you did allready the easiest way to fix this is setting your `PATH`. Basically your computer is looking for a binary in the Android SDK root folder and is not finding. By adding your Android SDK root directory to your path you will tell your OS where to look for the  binaries. How to set your PATH depends on your operating System and there is a billion guides on how to do it if you google it.

If you are using Android Studio there is a tool to get the SDK in Tools>SDK Manager. If you are not using Android Studio you can take a look at 
[this.](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools)